# How do I connect with Gremlin in dot Net?

Tags: database, graph, gremlin, tinkerpop

I am studying gremlin. I need to connect gremlin to .net and below is my code:

```
internal class Program
{
    private const string Host = "localhost";
    private const int Port = 8182;
    private const string NameTraversalSource = "gmodern";

    [Obsolete]
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start");

        Graph graph = new Graph();

        var client = new GremlinClient(new GremlinServer(Host, Port));

        var g = graph.Traversal().WithRemote(new DriverRemoteConnection(client));

        g.AddV("person").Property("name", "marko");

        var re = g.V().HasLabel("person").Values<string>("name").ToList();
        foreach (var c in re)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("End");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I don't know why it doesn't answer the desired result. I added vertex and name property with value of "marko". I need to print it out. But it doesn't print. Why? Help me.

Answer (score 1):

I voted to close this as I thought more details were required, but I think I realize the problem. In many ways the question could be closed as more of a "duplicate" as many Gremlin oriented questions tend to have this answer: [You need to iterate your traversal](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/#result-iteration).

The following line does nothing:

```
g.AddV("person").Property("name", "marko");
```

All it does is create a traversal (i.e. an `Iterator`). It does not execute it. To execute you must iterate it with some form of terminal step. Since you are aren't doing anything with the result you should probably use `iterate()` like:

```
g.AddV("person").Property("name", "marko").iterate();
```